# How to use @Transactional in java

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have 2 public method (to make it easy to understand I simplify them)
First method call second. My question is if I use @Transactional correctly. When I call this method from other class they should be in transaction

```
@Transactional
public int f1(Integer a) {
    return f2(a.toString());
}

@Transactional
public int f2(String b) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: No, you might want to read the documentation and try to run one of the examples from Spring to understand how it works.

Comment: is it Spring or javax.transaction?

Comment: The transaction propagation attribute control how the transaction takes effect when both method is marked as transactional.Check this.

Comment: yes it is spring transaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be kept in mind that calling a transactional method from the same bean will not work because it bypasses transactional proxy. In the above example, call from1 f1 to f2 actually ignores Transactional annotation on f2 method. It still works becuase f1 is transactional too.

Comment: If the advice is being applied using AspectJ, then the same-bean `@Transactional` does work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you don't necessarily need the `@Transactional` around `f1` unless you're doing something inside that method that needs to access persistent data. If you're using Spring's proxy AOP setup, then only method calls coming from another class will work, because the proxy AOP works by inserting a wrapper object around all of the class's methods. If you're using AspectJ, `@Transactional` advice will work properly even with `private` methods.

Comment: I dissagree because of proxy.

Comment: @hudi You're right in the case of proxy AOP; I typically use AspectJ and forgot about this restriction (it's one of the reasons why). Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

By using Transaction Propagation you can achieve what ever you want.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation